# I'm faced with grub rescue and desperately need to get windows7 booted again

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-7, grubrescue

I got message that installation of Ubuntu 15.x was successful (installed beside Windows7).  Now I'm stuck with grub rescue (whatever that means?).
From a similar mistakes several years ago I used to have a b&w screen with boot option menu on it 1. Windows 2. Ubuntu when I would boot up.  Can't find it and it's not coming up automatically. 
I'd be happy to wipe Ubuntu completely if that is what it takes.  I've got Recovery and repair disks for windows7 but nothing is really getting me started.
Help urgently needed.  Thank you

Geoff

Comment: UEFI or BIOS? Most Windows 7 systems are BIOS, but some have UEFI hardware. If BIOS: How to restore the Ubuntu/XP/Vista/7 bootloader 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestoreUbuntu/XP/Vista/7Bootloader or: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/681-startup-repair.html